# First argument to append must be slice; have struct - golang map

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, append, slice

Can't seem to use `append` for this case. Any help would be appreciated.

First argument to `append` must be slice:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type C struct {
    value5 string
    value6 string
}

type B struct {
    value3  string
    value4  C
}

type A struct {
    value1 string
    value2 B
}

type X struct{
    key     int
}
func main() {

    letSee := map[X]A{}
    letSee[X{1}]=A{"T",B{"T1",C{"T11","T12"}}}
    letSee[X{1}]=append(letSee[X{1}], A{"L",B{"L1",C{"L11","L12"}}})

    fmt.Println(letSee)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/R4gDO9MPBS

Comment: Is your intention to have a map that maps X to a slice of A? letSee := make(map[X][]A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in a map you want to store multiple values associated with the same key, the value type must be suitable for that. A struct isn't, but a [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) is a perfect choice.

So change your value type to `[]A`:

```
letSee := map[X][]A{}
letSee[X{1}] = []A{A{"T", B{"T1", C{"T11", "T12"}}}}
letSee[X{1}] = append(letSee[X{1}], A{"L", B{"L1", C{"L11", "L12"}}})

fmt.Printf("%+v", letSee)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/g1-aWge1IA)):

```
map[{key:1}:[{value1:T value2:{value3:T1 value4:{value5:T11 value6:T12}}}
    {value1:L value2:{value3:L1 value4:{value5:L11 value6:L12}}}]]
```